# Java Jackson Custom Polymorphc Deserializer to encrypt/decrypt fields

Tags: java, json, encryption, jackson, deserialization

I have certain fields of certain objects that, when serialized for storage in DB, need to be encrypted.

They need not being encrypted while in memory. I want to achieve this in a transparent way to the rest of the codebase, so I thought to put the enc/dec step at the ser/deser level.

In order to be generic, I have created an interface and an annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "__TYPE__")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type1.class, name = "Type1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type2.class, name = "Type2"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type3.class, name = "Type3")
})

@JsonSerialize(using=EncryptedSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=EncryptedDeserializer.class)
public interface EncryptedType {}
```

and

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface EncryptedField {}
```

The idea is that the classes will implement the empty interface to be matched to a custom ser/deser, which reflectively finds the fields and does its magic if they are annotated. The serialization step works like a charm, and I get an output string like:
    {"**TYPE**":"Type1","encryptedField":"aGAzLwT47gE/QNlUuAhnJg==","unencryptedField":"plaintext"}

But the decryption is terrible. I can't make it work: I'm unsure of what things to implement to combine the polymorphism AND the decryption.

If I remove the @JsonDeserialize annotation, and let Jackson do its thing, it deserialize polymorphically correctly but with the encrypted fields. If I try to use my custom deserializer, I get all sorts of errors from NPE to Jackson ones. What I want to achieve in my deserializer is something like:

1. Jackson, deserialize this thing as you know how using the type info with the encrypted fields
2. before returning, let me do my decryption on the instance (needs not to be typed correctly, I can access through reflection).

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class EncryptedDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<EncryptedType> {
[..super etc..]


@Override
public EncryptedType deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public EncryptedType deserializeWithType(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt,
        TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer) throws IOException {
    EncryptedType newInstance = super.deserializeWithType(p, ctxt, typeDeserializer);

    Field[] fields = newInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(EncryptedField.class)) {
            boolean accessibility = field.isAccessible();
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                field.set(newInstance, ApplicationContextRegister.getApplicationContext().getBean(TextEncryptionService.class).decrypt((String) field.get(newInstance)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Could not decryption field " + field.getName() + " of " + newInstance + ". Skipping decryption");
            }
            field.setAccessible(accessibility);
        }
    }
    return newInstance;
}
```

But this fails with errors or complaining about EncryptedDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor or I really have tried different options but I keep on getting stuck.

Comment: jackson-crypto on github does this, but generates a little bit different output.  It uses bean serialization modifiers to wrap other (de)serializers.  You can find the code for this [here](https://github.com/meltmedia/jackson-crypto/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/meltmedia/jackson/crypto).

Answer (score -1):

You need the `@JsonTypeInfo` stuff for polymorphism, as you've deduced.

A custom deserializer is one way to achieve your encryption logic.  If you wanted, you could always try a `@JsonCreator` annotation on your constructor for deserialization (and include the decryption logic in there) and have encryption handled by `@JsonProperty` annotations on customised getters.

Regarding the specific error of "EncryptedDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor" - why not just create one (even if it's `private`)?  Jackson uses such things for instantiation via reflection.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example on how to implement a custom polymorphic deserializer (no decrtyption)? The technicality of how to do that is what is lbocking me, not the decryption. The issue with the constructor is just one of the many things I tried and failed to achieve, I know how to put one there but it still won't work. I'm unaware on HOW do I do polymorphic custom deserializers, and that's what stopping me

Comment: As per https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html, `@JsonDeserialize` is "Annotation used for configuring deserialization aspects, by attaching to "setter" methods or fields, or to value classes".  I don't think you can apply it directly to an interface, though you should be able to apply it to an abstract class.

I'll try to come up with a working example, stand by.